# C++ Custom memory allocation link error in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I get the following linker error when I try to override the default memory allocation functions in VS2012:

> 1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned
>   int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)
>   1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)"
>   (??3@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)
>   1>c:\users\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\CustomMemoryAllocator\Debug\CustomMemoryAllocator.exe :
>   fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Here is my code (I get no intellisense errors):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void *operator new(size_t size){
    if(void *mem = malloc(size)){
        cout << "allocated memory" << endl;
        return mem;
    }
    else{
        throw bad_alloc();
    }
}

void operator delete(void* mem) throw() {
    cout << "deleting" << endl;
    free(mem);
}

int main(){
    cout << "test";
    int* a = new int(4);
    delete a;
    int b = 0;
    cin >> b;
}
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries not getting linked in correct order

Trying adding at top of your file

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/nodefaultlib:libc.lib")
#pragma comment(linker, "/nodefaultlib:libcd.lib")
```

Else follow [these](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148652) instructions.

Comment: Excellent! Could you elaborate a little on the problem- may be for the general problem? Is this a problem limited to VS? What do your lines do? What causes this problem?

Thanks

Comment: @user997112 well when MFC and CRT happen to get link in incorrect order overload of `new`, `delete`, fails badly. Microsoft page explains the cause in detail.
Those `pragma` directives are for linker to takeoff those libs
Yes, this happens on VC++ only, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a DLL instead of static linking the libraries.  Go to project properties / C++ / Code Generation / Runtime Library and pick the DLL option.

Windows calls a DLL or EXE a module.  A module is not allowed to multiply define a symbol, but two different modules used by one process can define the same symbol.  When using a DLL, operator new() is defined in both your and the MSVC module which causes no error.

Comment: Hi- could you elaborate on the differences/consequences of the DLL option vs the static option? Thanks